# Acoustic Echo Cancellation in gstreamer

Tags: c, linux, gstreamer, voip, rtp

I am developing a Voip apps using gstreamer, i created the apps using the rtp example in gstreamer, i put the client and the server in the same code and each in a process, i made it work but the problem was with the echo, so i tried to implement the speex aec but the problem was that i've only the input of the mic but i can't have the output from the speaker.

the part of the voice sending is

```
 pipeline = gst_pipeline_new (NULL);
  g_assert (pipeline);

  /* the audio capture and format conversion */
  audiosrc = gst_element_factory_make (AUDIO_SRC, "audiosrc");
  g_assert (audiosrc);
  audioconv = gst_element_factory_make ("audioconvert", "audioconv");
  g_assert (audioconv);
  audiores = gst_element_factory_make ("audioresample", "audiores");
  g_assert (audiores);
  /* the encoding and payloading */
  audioenc = gst_element_factory_make (AUDIO_ENC, "audioenc");
  g_assert (audioenc);
  audiopay = gst_element_factory_make (AUDIO_PAY, "audiopay");
  g_assert (audiopay);

  /* add capture and payloading to the pipeline and link */
  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), audiosrc, audioconv, audiores,
      audioenc, audiopay, NULL);

  if (!gst_element_link_many (audiosrc, audioconv, audiores, audioenc,
          audiopay, NULL)) {
    g_error ("Failed to link audiosrc, audioconv, audioresample, "
        "audio encoder and audio payloader");
  }
```

and the part that receive voice

```
    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), rtpsrc, rtcpsrc, rtcpsink, NULL);

  /* the depayloading and decoding */
  audiodepay = gst_element_factory_make (AUDIO_DEPAY, "audiodepay");
  g_assert (audiodepay);
  audiodec = gst_element_factory_make (AUDIO_DEC, "audiodec");
  g_assert (audiodec);
  /* the audio playback and format conversion */
  audioconv = gst_element_factory_make ("audioconvert", "audioconv");
  g_assert (audioconv);
  audiores = gst_element_factory_make ("audioresample", "audiores");
  g_assert (audiores);
  audiosink = gst_element_factory_make (AUDIO_SINK, "audiosink");
  g_assert (audiosink);

  /* add depayloading and playback to the pipeline and link */
  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), audiodepay, audiodec, audioconv,
      audiores, audiosink, NULL);

  res = gst_element_link_many (audiodepay, audiodec, audioconv, audiores,
      audiosink, NULL);
  g_assert (res == TRUE);
```

haw can i use the speex AEC?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is now an echo canceller included in upstream GStreamer. It will be shipped with GStreamer 1.10. It is using the DSP module from WebRTC project, which is much better then speex. I would recommend using that. Simple usage on an echo loop:

```
gst-launch-1.0 autoaudiosrc ! webrtcdsp ! webrtcechoprobe ! autoaudiosink
```

See http://ndufresne.ca/2016/06/gstreamer-echo-canceller/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the "the output from the speaker", you need the audio that is being sent to the speakers.

Comment: In fact, in the speex echo canceller, speex_echo_cancellation(echo_state, input_frame, echo_frame, output_frame);
so we need one with echo from the mic and one from the speakers, to substract the speakers signal from what is sent to the mic!

Comment: The AEC needs to get two signals: 1. what you capture form the mic (which also contains the echo of course) 2. what you are sending to the speakers in order to be played.

Comment: So the problem with the second one, because this two signals are in different process, how can i extracted with gstreamer?